# Is there an option to delete old photos off my iPod?

Tags: data-synchronization, photos, ipod, macos

I have no option to delete old photos off my iPod. They are old photos, by that I mean they were on my iPod then I got them off, and about a year later (I had synced it a couple of times in between) I synced my iPod to my laptop and they all came back with no option to delete them off.

Comment: Did they come back to your laptop or iPod? If it's both, then you can turn off Photo Syncrizonation in iTunes,

Answer (score 1):

You can choose what should synchronise, from iTunes > [iDevice] > Photos

You can switch off sync entirely, or choose from Albums, Events, Faces; whether to include videos & whether to automatically add recent Events.

[image]